# Powershell script for moving folders in repository to right subfolder

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script which will read project names (one per line) from file `e:\projects.txt` and for each project find all subfolders in folder `e:\repository` who has project name in the folder name and move them to folder `e:\projects\projectname`

for one project the command would be:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "e:\repository" -Filter *ProjectName1* -Directory | 
   Move-Item -Destination "E:\projects\ProjectName1" -Recurse
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If the found folder name matches exactly the line from should it the be moved to a **sub**folder of that name? And do all the project name folders already exist?

Comment: Hi, found folder only contains project name, there is other data in the folder name. Project names folders doesn't exist always.